# check if newer version of docker image is available

Tags: docker

I have a private docker repository and I want to check if a newer version of the docker image is available or not. I have tried :

```
curl -kvu "myuser:mypasswd" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X HEAD https://myrepo:5000/v2/myimage/manifests/i386
```

I got response like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 9080
< Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
< Docker-Content-Digest: sha256:5891d3d01fcdb5ec7dc8a27f25360b132510c7b92369ad50926c27ca7d7cfacf
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Etag: "sha256:5891d3d01fcdb5ec7dc8a27f25360b132510c7b92369ad50926c27ca7d7cfacf"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Which field in the response header is to be compared with the local image metadata?

Comment: Docker-Content-Digest: field should be checked against the digest of local image. I have found out, but the 64 bit docker clients show the local image digests correctly. 32 bit clients are showing as None. This is the main issue now. I have a lot of 32 bit servers running docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -kvu "myuser:mypasswd" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X HEAD https://myrepo:5000/v2/myimage/manifests/<tag>
```

Will return a response like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 9080
< Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
< Docker-Content-Digest: sha256:5891d3d01fcdb5ec7dc8a27f25360b132510c7b92369ad50926c27ca7d7cfacf
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Etag: "sha256:5891d3d01fcdb5ec7dc8a27f25360b132510c7b92369ad50926c27ca7d7cfacf"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

`Docker-Content-Digest:` field should be checked against the `digest` of local image

```
docker images --digests myrepo:5000/myimage
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myrepo:5000/myimage   i386                sha256:5891d3d01fcdb5ec7dc8a27f25360b132510c7b92369ad50926c27ca7d7cfacf   b9e9c7f4a462        6 days ago          491 MB
```

`docker images --digests myrepo:5000/myimage` Should be run without the tag (i386 in this case)

If the digests mismatches, then there is a newer version of the image available. **So basically, you check the digest of the remote and the local image. If they mismatch, a newer version is available.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ready-to-use shell script to check it against GitLab's Docker Registry.

```bsh
set -e

GITLAB_SERVER="xxx.example.com"
REGISTRY_SERVER="$GITLAB_SERVER:5001"
IMAGE="group/subgroup1/subgroup2/project/image"

AUTH=$(jq -r ".auths.\"$REGISTRY_SERVER\".auth" ~/.docker/config.json | base64 -d)  # WARN: on OSX base64 -D not -d
TOKEN=$(curl -u "$AUTH" "https://$GITLAB_SERVER/jwt/auth?client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=container_registry&scope=repository:$IMAGE:push,pull" | jq -r .token)
REMOTE_SHA=$(curl -fH "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -I https://$REGISTRY_SERVER/v2/$IMAGE/manifests/latest | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print $2}')
LOCAL_SHA=$(docker inspect "$REGISTRY_SERVER/${IMAGE}:latest"  -f '{{index .Id}}')

echo "Local:  $LOCAL_SHA"
echo "Remote: $REMOTE_SHA" 

if [[ "$LOCAL_SHA" == "$REMOTE_SHA" ]]; then
  echo "$IMAGE up-to-date"
else
  echo "$IMAGE outdated"
fi
```